# PostgreSQL: Remotely connecting to Postgres instance using psql command

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to remotely connect to a Postgres instance. I know we can do this using the psql command passing the hostname

I tried the following:

```
psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h hostname
```

I modified the /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf file on the target machine to allow remote connections by default

I added the following line to the file

```
host all all source_ip/32 trust
```

I restarted the cluster using

```
pg_ctlcluster 9.2 mycluster stop
pg_ctlcluster 9.2 mycluster start
```

However, when I try to connect from the source_ip, I still get the error

> Is the server running on host "" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What operating system the postgres server runs on?

Comment: check you firewall settings, so port 5432 is open to accept connections

Comment: Assuming your client machine has `ssh` you can also try localhost-like connection to remote postgres simply by setting ssh tunnel: `ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 your_server_ip` and connecting the same way as you would connect to localhost db. This can help debugging.

Comment: By default postgresql only listens on localhost (and many distro's leave this default untouched) adjust the value of listen_addresses to '*' to make postgresql listen on all addresses your machine has.

Comment: Show the **full error message** not jut the hint.

Comment: @Dmitry : my postgresql is on an ec2 instance and I have configured the security group to allow connection on port 5432

Comment: @jangorecki : unable to connect using the command. It asks for public key authentication which fails

Comment: @CraigRinger : the full message is 
psql: could not connect to server: connection refused
Is the server running on host "" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: @Eelke : where am I add the entry that you have specified. are you saying that I should write 
host all all * trust in pg_hba.conf

Comment: The error is 'connection refused' so pg_hba.conf is not involved. Most likely listen_addresses is bound to just localhost.

Comment: @CraigRinger : where can I find the parameter listen_addresses?

Comment: in `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf`

Comment: many thanks @CraigRinger and Eelke... you both saved my day.. setting listen_addresses='*' was the key

Comment: follow this link: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/23/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I figured it out.

Had to set `listen_addresses='*'` in `postgresql.conf` to allow for incoming connections from any ip / all ip

Comment: Is this a security concern or is this considered a normal practice?

Comment: @Ben Generally speaking, one should allow only specific IP addresses to connect to psql instance.

Comment: @Ben you should use the firewall to limit access to your Postgres instance. The firewall inside Postgres is redundant IMO.

Answer (score 150):

I resolved this issue using below options:

1. Whitelist your DB host from your network team to make sure you have access to remote host
2. Install postgreSQL version 4 or above
3. Run below command:

   ```
   psql -h <REMOTE HOST> -p <REMOTE PORT> -U <DB_USER> <DB_NAME>
   ```

Comment: I use ElephantSql and the following worked: `psql -h <surus.db.elephantsql.com> -U <user>`. The host can change in the free version, then I had to add the password, which is separated with colon from the user in the URL String.

Answer (score 65):

```
psql -h <IP_Address> -p <port_no> -d <database_name> -U <DB_username> -W
```

`-W` option will prompt for password. For example:

```
psql -h 192.168.1.50 -p 5432 -d testdb -U testuser -W
```

Comment: for me, it also prompted for password without `-W` option

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use a `postgres` url you can just do something like this:

```bash
psql postgres://user:password@ip_add_or_domain:port/db_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Step Wise below

1. Opening the Port - Make sure the PSQL Port is open to all remote connections or connections from a specific set of IPs as per your requirement. PSQL, in general, runs at port 5432, and it is configurable, so expose relevant Port accordingly.
2. Update Remote Server PSQL Configuration  - Set `listen_addresses = '*'` in `postgresql.conf` file, path in general is `/etc/postgresql/psql_version/main/postgresql.conf`
3. Connect remotely - `psql -U <db_username> -h <IP_address>` - in case  psql is running on a port other than 5432 on the remote server, specify port by adding `-p <port_number>`

A little plus below -
In case the IP has been mapped to a domain name, you can connect by replacing `<IP_address>` with `<host_name>`. To do this, add a new connection rule in `pg_hba.conf` file

Note -
All above explained can cause security issues - best practice always is to either keep your psql port closed, or only allow a list of IPs to connect through the port.

Answer (score 0):

Note that "ident" in pg_hba.conf requires a "ident server" to be running on the client.